# after logout do not go back to previous page in jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp

To prevent user to go back after logout i used following code in `home.jsp` page

```
<% 
if (session.getAttribute("authe") != null && session.getAttribute("authe").equals(true)) {

}
else {  
    response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
}
%>
```

and I invalidated the session in `logout.jsp`.

It worked fine but when I pressed back button after logout it still goes to home page but after reloading that home page it moves to the login page.
I thought it it due to the browser default action.

How to make it to work effectively?

Comment: Have you ruled out caching?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `home.jsp` put header as `no-cache`:

```
<%
   response.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache,no-store,private,must-revalidate,max-stale=0,post-check=0,pre-check=0"); 
   response.addHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); 
   response.addDateHeader ("Expires", 0);
 %>
```

Comment: this didn't work for me but @Deepak Singh answer works.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
<%
try {
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache");
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-store");
    response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache");
    response.setDateHeader ("Expires", 0);
    if (session.getAttribute("userid")==null) {
        response.sendRediredirect("login.jsp");
    }
    else {}
}
catch(Exception ex) {
    out.println(ex);
}
%>
```